# How do I parse this Dynamo DB data into Android from an API from Amazon API Gateway?

Tags: android, json, parsing, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

My Code - I'm trying to return the data from JSON.

```
JSONObject count = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray itemsArray = count.getJSONArray("Items");
                JSONObject finalObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String record = finalObject.getString("myid");
                String vocabulary = finalObject.getString("vocab");
                String method = finalObject.getString("method");

                return record + vocabulary + method;
```

JSON I'm trying to parse- Count object, Items array, etc...

```
{ 

   "Count":1,

   "Items":[   
      { 
        "myid":{

            "S":"1"
         },
         "vocab":{   
            "S":"print a line"
         },
         "method":{  
            "S":"system.out.println"
         }
      }
   ],
   "ScannedCount":1
```

Comment: what do you want to return?

Comment: I am trying to return the ID record of 1, print a line, and system.out.println. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did not understand properly, paste your excepted output and also what output you are getting..

Answer (score 0):

If there is a fixed schema, you can transfer the DynamoDB JSON to JSON via a mapping template on API Gateway.

**Mapping Template**

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "items": [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
            "myid": "$elem.myid.S",
            "vocab": "$elem.vocab.S",
            "method": "$elem.method.S"
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
    ]
}
```

Then, you can parse the JSON String from API Gateway in your Android application into an object.

**Sample parsing code**

```
public class Items {
    private List<Item> items;
    //getters and setters
}

public class Item {
    private String myid;
    private String vocab;
    private String message;
    //getters and setters
}

Items items;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
jsonData = .... // from API Gateway
items = mapper.readValue(jsonData, Items.class);
```

Also, there is better way to get those information from API Gateway's generated android SDK. In order to do so, you need to define a **Model Schema** and set to the method response, then once you **deploy** your API change this modification, you can download an android SDK for your API.

**Model Schema**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "items": {
      "type": "array",
      "item": {
        "properties": {
          "myid": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "vocab": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "method": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You might want to read [this step by step walkthrough](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-models.html) if you want to have more detail on how to mapping response work, and